# DotNetNuke MVC Module passing data to different route

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm trying to pass data to a different route. I use form action and `Url.Action` but that didn't work. It doesn't even route to another view. It works when I use the anchor tag href with `Url.Action`, but how do I pass data from one Controller method to the same Controller but a different method.

Comment: Any code to show what you have tried? what worked and what are you trying to achieve and how?

Comment: Have their been any updates on this question?

Answer (score 0):

I have a DNN MVC module example on Github for your reference.  https://github.com/DotNetNuclear/DnnRestaurantMenu/blob/master/RestaurantMenu.MVC. You can easily install it by finding the install package under the Releases link.

If you look at the default/index view, there is a link to open the Edit view. If passed an item ID, it will load the data into the edit form, otherwise, with no item ID, it considers it a new (add) item.

So in my View.cshtml, I use DNN's Url.Action helper which forms the button's href. (https://github.com/DotNetNuclear/DnnRestaurantMenu/blob/master/RestaurantMenu.MVC/Views/Menu/Index.cshtml)

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Menu", new {ctl = "Edit", itemId = item.MenuItemId})">@Dnn.LocalizeString("EditItem")</a>
```

The first parameter is the module control key/action.  The second is the controller name. In the 3rd parameter of Url.Action we pass the control type and then any number of additional querystring parameters.  In this case, the item Id that is in the view's model.

In my MenuController's Edit() action, I can then take that item ID parameter to lookup the item model from the database and then return the Edit view.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int itemId = -1)
{
    ...

    if (itemId > 0)
    {
        item = _menuController.GetItem(itemId, CurrentModuleId);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have every been able to do this with no headache is to create a routerconfig.cs:

```
using DotNetNuke.Web.Mvc.Routing;
using RouteParameter = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter;

namespace CodeWompler.CW.GridTest
{
    public class RouteConfig : IMvcRouteMapper
    {
        public void RegisterRoutes(IMapRoute mapRouteManager)
        {
            mapRouteManager.MapRoute(
                moduleFolderName:"CW.GridTest", 
                routeName: "CW.GridTest", 
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{userid}/{itemid}", 
                defaults: new {
                    id=RouteParameter.Optional,
                    userid=RouteParameter.Optional,
                    itemid=RouteParameter.Optional
                },
                namespaces: new[] {"CodeWompler.CW.GridTest.Controllers"});
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in my index.cshtml, for instance, I can do this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: `/DesktopModules/MVC/CW.GridTest/IMMUser/EditUserById/userid/${myUserId}`,
        method: "Post",
        headers: {
            "ModuleId": moduleId,
            "TabId": tabId,
            "RequestVerificationToken": rvtoken,
            "userId": id //if we were to specify Edit as our url, then we would need this since Edit() takes no parameters and instead, looks in the header for it's data.
        }
```

or 
`/DesktopModules/MVC/CW.GridTest/IMMUser/EditUserById/${myUserId}`

or

`/DesktopModules/MVC/CW.GridTest/IMMUser/AssignItemToUser/userid/${myUserId}/itemid/${myItemId}`